# what features of Google Analytics can be used in Electron-Vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-analytics, electron, desktop-application

I have created an education application with electron-vue js and now I have decided to implement Google Analytics in this desktop application. I have googled for some [packages](https://github.com/jaystack/electron-ga) but could not find what exactly I can get from Google Analytics i.e., what features of google analytics I should use to improve my study-based desktop application( electron-vue js platform).
Here is a little bit description about it:
a) the application is totally offline.
b) it includes study stuff like audios,videos,etc.,.
c) it also provides features like printing study material.
Even a single idea can help me figuring out what to do with Google analytics and can be a good head start.
Thanking you in advance!

Comment: If it's totally offline, how do you plan to send data to Google Analytics? Edit: There's a pretty solid guide here: https://kilianvalkhof.com/2018/apps/using-google-analytics-to-gather-usage-statistics-in-electron/ explaining on how to implement GA in to Electron apps but it must be online to achieve this. Also be aware that you need to implement GDPR if it's in Europe.

Comment: Also, why do you need it? What are your goals? What are you trying to achieve? Without knowing exactly _what_ your reason is for needing Google Analytics specifically, then it's hard to provide you with a proper answer. Is it even necessary? Are there other solutions for tracking functionality? Are you trying to track user actions? Button clicks? Material downloads? Only you know what you want to achieve, until you know, we don't know what you want to use Google Analytics for specifically. Other than that, to answer literally, _all_ features work with an Eletron app. :-)

Comment: I use vue-analytics in my projects. Works pretty good for this.  https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics will consider Electron a website.

I use this plugin https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics

And set it up like this in your main entry for Vue in your renderer

```
import VueAnalytics, { set } from 'vue-analytics'
Vue.use(VueAnalytics, {
    id: 'UA-idnumber',
    router,
    // debug: {
    //   enabled: true,
    //   trace: true // help you find problems
    // },
    fields: {
      cookieDomain: 'none' // no domain
    },
    autoTracking: {
      pageviewTemplate (route) {
        // allow custom page titles in the router meta
        let title = route.meta.title
        if (!title) {
          title = route.name
        }
        return {
          page: route.name,
          title: title,
          location: route.path
        }
      }
    }
  })
  set('allowAdFeatures', false) // no ads
  set('checkProtocolTask', null) // ignore electron protocols
  set('checkStorageTask', null) // ignore electrons cache solution, assume it works
```

Then I have directives like this

```
import { event } from 'vue-analytics'
Vue.directive('gaClick',
      {
        inserted: (el, binding, vnode) => {
          let routeName = vnode.context.$route.meta.title
          if (!routeName) {
            routeName = vnode.context.$route.name
          }
          el.addEventListener('click', async e => {
            const category = binding.value && binding.value.category ? binding.value.category : 'button Click'
            const action = binding.value && binding.value.action ? binding.value.action : 'Click'
            const label = binding.value && binding.value.label ? binding.value.label : `${e.target.innerText} (${routeName})`
            const value = binding.value && binding.value.value ? binding.value.value : 0
            event(category, action, label, value)
          })
        }
      })
```

To be used on buttons and links like this

```
<router-link
        :to="{name:'status-page'}}"
        v-ga-click="{label:'Status Page'}"
      >
      Status Page
</router-link>
```

This will give you nearly all the features google analytics has. Unless they decide to change things again and break it. Like they did in their push to firebase analytics for "apps"